# How can I merge two arrays of objects, possibly different lengths, filtering out some values based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let us say I have two arrays like the following:

```
const arr1 = [
    {id:1, value:25},
    {id:2, value:15},
    {id:3, value:35}
];

const arr2 = [
    {id:3, value:95},
    {id:4, value:65}
];
```

And I want a third array that includes the 3 items with unique id's, but for the two objects with repeating id's (id:3) - I want to keep the same ID and add the values. Ending up with something like...

```
const arr3 = [
    {id:1, value:25},
    {id:2, value:15},
    {id:3, value:130},
    {id:4, value:65},
];
```

So I need the most efficient way to find the objects with the same ID's, then do some logic to merge their values and add the merged object back to the new, combined, array.

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: `const arr3 = Array.from([ ...arr1, ...arr2 ].reduce((idToSum, { id, value }) => idToSum.set(id, (idToSum.get(id) ?? 0) + value), new Map()), ([ id, value ]) => ({ id, value }));`.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I tried mapping over one of the arrays, and using .includes to find duplicates - but first - i need to compare a property within the objects of the array, not the objects themselves. And second, the arrays may be different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple js object to keep track of the `ids`, so you can lookup for an `id` in `O(1)` time, like it's already in use or not.

1. Merge two arrays
2. Iterate through the merged array and build a dictionary using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
3. In every iteration look for the `id` in the dictionary or not. if the id is not present we insert the new key as `id` and the value as `{id, value}`. and if the key is present we need to add the previous value with the new value and finally update it.

```js
const arr1 = [ {id:1, value:25}, {id:2, value:15}, {id:3, value:35} ]; 
const arr2 = [ {id:3, value:95}, {id:4, value:65} ];
 
const res = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((a, {id, value}) => ({...a, [id]: a[id] ? {id, value: a[id].value + value} : {id, value}}), {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```